# Incremental Loading In a Sortable and Filterable Table

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, file-io, disk-io

**Background**

I am developing an HTML table which has data from ~50,000 small sized (~4KB) XML files. Each XML feeds a row in the table, with each XML node being a column of the table (7 nodes per file). The table supports column level sorting and filtering (like you see in the Excel spreadsheets).

**Problem**

I am loading all ~50k files in one go and then determining the order of them in memory. This is causing some time (excessive loading time ~2 minutes) and memory performance issues. I want to know how other people are solving this problem or if they have any ideas to tackle this.

**What have I tried**

Incremental loading does not seem to be an option since I am supporting the column level sorting and filtering, I have to load all ~50k files in one go and then determine the order of them in memory. I have seen people naming the XML file to have all the sort able column values but since I have many columns with large strings, including them in the name does not seem feasible.

Comment: Create an external index. An example could be to create another xml file for each column which contains the columns data and the corresponding file name. *how other people are solving this problem* - they usually just use the correct data store for this (e.g. a database).

Comment: How using the database would solve this problem? Would I be able to load the data in the desired sort order or a pre-applied filter?

Comment: The question is really too broad, can't be answered as is (there are too many possible solutions). If you load the metadata of your XML files inside any database, then you can just query it and sort/filter the results as you want.

Comment: Is your HTML bound to any visible control?  Usually delays like this is due to a control getting refresh.

Comment: I am getting the HTML from web server and replacing the table's HTML with it whenever I am loading the files. Is that what you mean when you say control getting refresh?